# Bubble-sort with user's input = error

Tags: java, bubble-sort

There is some mistake when I try to call my bubble sort class. But I cannot find it. 
This is my bubble sort class, which should be ok:

```
public static void Sort2(double[] yourNumbers) {
        double swap; 
        for(int i = 0; i < yourNumbers.length-1; i++){
            for(int d = 0; d < yourNumbers.length-1; d++){
                if(yourNumbers[d] > yourNumbers[d+1]){ 
                    //swap feature
                    swap = yourNumbers[d];
                    yourNumbers[d] = yourNumbers[d+1];
                    yourNumbers[d+1] = swap;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is my main method (and here when I call the `Sort2` method I got an error:

> The method Sort2(double[]) in the type sort.java is not applicable for
>   the arguments (int)

```
        System.out.println("Size");
        int yourNumbers = scan.nextInt();
        double[] array = new double[yourNumbers];

        System.out.println("Numbers");

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
            array[i] = scan.nextDouble();

        }
            Sort2(array);
```

I know it was asked here so many times, but I feel I can't get it right. Please can you help me ?
PS: I am not allowed to use an `ArrayList`.

EDIT : THis is code i used now. Stil wont work:
Edit 2 : With help of this http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/70sorting.html I got that. One line solves everything

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bublesort{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Size");
        int yourNumbers = scan.nextInt();
        double[] array = new double[yourNumbers];

        System.out.println("Numbers");

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
            array[i] = scan.nextDouble();
         }

       Sort2(array);
    **System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));** 

    }
    public static void Sort2(double[] yourNumbers) {
        double swap; 
         for(int i = 0; i < yourNumbers.length - 1; i++){
                for(int d = i + 1; d < yourNumbers.length; d++){
                    if(yourNumbers[i] > yourNumbers[d]){ 
                        //swap feature
                        swap = yourNumbers[i];
                        yourNumbers[i] = yourNumbers[d];
                        yourNumbers[d] = swap;

                    }
                }
            }

    }}
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `Sort2()` method? I don't see this being called from your `main()` method.

Comment: call Sort2(array) instead of Sort2(yourNumbers);

Comment: Yes, thank i added Sort2 method

Comment: are you stillgetting compiler error orthecodedoesnt work??

Comment: no, the code works, but what the code does is not what i want. When user types different double numbers it should sort with help of Buble-alg.

Comment: you don't have any output after sorting the array ;)

Comment: System.out.println(array[i]); < Somthing like this

Comment: Got that, with help of sort method http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/70sorting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `ArrayList` you must import `java.util.ArrayList;` You are getting the error because you are passing an integer to your Sort2() function.  You need to pass it an array of doubles.  Also, your sort2 function will sort the array, but you will have no way to reference it, because java passes arguments by value.. you should have your function `double[] sort2(double[] array)` and then return the sorted array.

Comment: Oh, you mean you are not allowed to use the ArrayList class... That was ambiguity on your part, and my answer is still a solution for you. No downvote necessary...

Comment: But you're wrong on the reference part! The value of the reference is passed, therefore the changes will affect the original array! Perfect example: Arrays.sort() is a void method...

Comment: What will this print<br />`int[] array = {3,2,1};`<br />`Arrays.sort(array);`<br />`for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`<br />`System.out.println(array[i]);`<br />My point has nothing to do with arraylist

Comment: Look at [Arrays.sort();](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[]))

Comment: all arguments are passed by value in java: correct! For arguments, which are reference data types, the value of the reference is passed. So the argument is a reference to the same object as the paramater.

Comment: Check this little demo, and try to explain it :) http://pastebin.com/ChQ7rR46

Answer (score 0):

the error says that you cant pass an `int` to a method which accepts `double[]` as an `argument`.

```
   System.out.println("Size");
        int yourNumbers = scan.nextInt();
        double[] array = new double[yourNumbers];

        System.out.println("Numbers");

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
            array[i] = scan.nextDouble();
         }

       sort2(array);//**should work fine**
```

Comment: Even this sollution doesn't work.

Comment: what does the error say?? can u  please post your relevant code where you are getting an error??

Answer (score 0):

Better version of sort routine should look something like: N*(n-1) / 2 iterations vs n^2

```
         for(int i = 0; i < yourNumbers.length - 1; i++){
            for(int d = i + 1; d < yourNumbers.length; d++){
                if(yourNumbers[i] > yourNumbers[d]){ 
                    //swap feature
                    swap = yourNumbers[i];
                    yourNumbers[i] = yourNumbers[d];
                    yourNumbers[d] = swap;

                }
            }
        }
```